# Pagination class based views django 1.5

Tags: python, regex, django, pagination

I'm developing a website based on Django==1.5.7

I need to paginate the `ListView` of a table in my application.

This is the code i'm using

On models.py:

```
class UsuarioFidetel(models.Model):
"""
Modelo de usuario fidetel
"""

usuario = models.CharField(max_length=30)
id_usuario = models.IntegerField()
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
apellido = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
tipo_cedula = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True)
cedula = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True)
fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True)
correo = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True)
estado_civil = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre
```

On views.py:

```
class UsarioList(ListView):
model = UsuarioFidetel
template_name = 'all_list.html'
```

On urls.py:

```
url(r'^usario/$', UsarioList.as_view(model=UsuarioFidetel, paginate_by=2)),
```

Note the `paginate_by` attribute of the url, this is working just fine, but when I go to the 2nd page, or whatever page, outside the 1st one, it throws this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:9001/usario?page=2
```

All is working fine, but I thought this will pass the page inside the block of my template, without major errors, can't figure out what's wrong here, maybe I need a regex on the url?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, solved it on template, ie:

```
<span class="page-links">
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a href="/fidetel/usario?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&lt;</a>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="page-current">
                Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a href="/fidetel/usario?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&gt;</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
```

Now it works the way it should